# Docker Swarm on GCP, LB works on one of the two instances

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-swarm

My architecture is as follows:

- 2 docker-dev-1 and docker-dev-2 nodes in a `docker-dev` VPC
- 2 docker-internal-1 and docker-internal-2 nodes in a `docker-internal` VPC
- The firewall allows `tcp:2377, 7946, udp:4789, 7946, esp` as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts)

All of them are masters in order to facilitate testing for the moment. Docker version is 20.10.16. All the instances are exactly the same (packages, configuration...).

Currently I have a flask/jinja application running on docker-dev-X.

**To connect to the database**, the app passes by a reverse proxy which redirects the streams that arrives on port 3306 (MySQL) to a Cloud SQL instance of the `docker-internal` VPC.
The flask application is exposed via a reverse proxy that listens on port `8082`.

[image: Architecture Schema]

Here is the docker `daemon.json` configuration:

```json
{
  "mtu": 1454,
  "no-new-privileges": true
}
```

**Everything works fine when I have only one docker-dev**. However, as soon as I add the docker-dev-2 node, all streams with a large output passing through `docker-dev-2` do not work.
Let me explain:

**On docker-dev-1 :**

```sh
dev@docker-dev-1:~$ curl localhost:8082/health
Ok

# With a heavier page

dev@docker-dev-1:~$ curl localhost:8082/auth/login
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_GB">
<head>
... # Lots of HTMLs
</html>
```

No problem everything is working fine.

**On docker-dev-2 :**

```sh
dev@docker-dev-2:~$ curl localhost:8082/health
Ok

dev@docker-dev-2:~$ curl -I localhost:8082/health
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 18 May 2022 12:34:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
...

# With a heavier page

devdocker-dev-2:~$ curl localhost:8082/auth/login
^C # Timeout

# Same curl but shows only header
dev@docker-dev-2:~$ curl -I localhost:8082/auth/login
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 18 May 2022 10:43:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 222967 # Long Content-Length
Connection: keep-alive
...
```

- As you can see, when I try to curl the `/health` --> No problem
- When I try to curl `/auth/login` --> The request timeout, I have no answer
- When I try to curl `/auth/login` to show only headers --> The request works

In a container, everything is working fine, on docker-dev-1 and on docker-dev-2 :

```sh
dev@docker-dev-2:~$ docker run -it --rm --name debug --network jinja_flask_network nicolaka/netshoot bash

bash-5.1# curl reverse_proxy_nginx/health:8082
Ok

bash-5.1# curl reverse_proxy_nginx:8082/auth/login

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_GB">
<head>
... # Lots of HTMLs
</html>
```

So the problem doesn't seem to be in docker network.

The problem seems to be when the request output is too long.

I already reduced MTU to 1454 a few months ago to resolve a problem... (Seems to be the same problem but in docker network).

So, when the request is on docker-dev-1 --> No problem, the website is loading normally, But when the request is on docker-dev-2 --> Infinite loading results in a timeout.

I hope I was clear in my explanation, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Verify the firewall by setting up tcpdump on each node, check that the outgoing packets on one node are received on the destination.

Comment: I did a tcpdump (justpaste.it/2imxh) we can see that my curl from docker-dev-2 to the public IP goes to docker-internal-1 and does the SQL query to my Cloud SQL instance. It's very difficult to catch the right dumps but I see packets on every expected nodes.

Comment: @AChichi : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: @HemanthKumar Unfortunately it's not resolved yet :(